# How to detect the mouse cursor/click in a previously recorded video/image frame

Tags: java, python, matlab, image-processing, video-capture

I have some screencasts that explain how to perform a task in a specific software. My objective is to detect where the user clicks on a button or menu item or anything else that leads to a change. One solution to this work is to detect the mouse cursor's location. There are several challenges:

1. The cursor's icon changes and is not always the same in all videos (e.g. Mac vs Win, arrow shaped and hand shaped cursors).
2. I tried template matching, but I did not get good results because the display settings of each person who is capturing the video may be different and therefore the size of the cursor will be different.
3. Calculating the difference between two consequent images can give the mouse cursors only in the output but I need to have only the second or the last image's cursor's location in the output not both of them.
4. I also tried to find an object tracking sample solution, but they are either for live videos or for multiple objects ( I only need to spot the mouse cursor or the locations where the mouse was clicked on)

I would appreciate if if anyone could suggest a solution, ready to use code (in Java/Matlab/Python), software or API for this work.

Comment: You can use java's MouseListener by implementing MouseListener.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html

Comment: The videos are already capured. They are youtube videos and I do not have access to the OS. Any idea about image processing approaches of doing this?

Comment: I misread this at first. So to make it clear: you are trying to detect in the contents of a video which is a screen cast of some tutorial or the like when and where a mouse click happens and if so on which button. Right?

Comment: @Fildor Yes that's exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?